# 'unsafe-eval' error from embedded typeform in HTML document | Google App Engine hosted

Tags: html, google-app-engine, typeform

I'm currently hosting a website on Google's App Engine. The HTML document just has an embedded typeform survey for visitors to fill out and submit. But under Chrome's developer tools I have two 'report ony' errors displaying `Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'report-sample'`.

A lot of similar issues I've found from others regarding 'unsafe-eval' are specific to Chrome extension apps, which I don't believe is applicable to this case, but I'm unsure. Below is the code to my html file and a screenshot of the errors shown under chrome's developer tools.

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/style2.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="typeform-widget" data-url="https://exampletypeform.typeform.com/to/xxxxxx" data-transparency="100" data-hide-headers=true data-hide-footer=true style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
      <script>
        (function() {
          var qs, js, q, s, d = document,
            gi = d.getElementById,
            ce = d.createElement,
            gt = d.getElementsByTagName,
            id = "typef_orm",
            b = "https://embed.typeform.com/";
          if (!gi.call(d, id)) {
            js = ce.call(d, "script");
            js.id = id;
            js.src = b + "embed.js";
            q = gt.call(d, "script")[0];
            q.parentNode.insertBefore(js, q)
          }
        })()
      </script>
      <div style="font-family: Sans-Serif;font-size: 12px;color: #999;opacity: 0.5; padding-top: 5px;"> powered by <a
          href="https://admin.typeform.com/signup?utm_campaign=pSRmVb&utm_source=typeform.com-01E2GSJH8NA4229V90SSW87KMS-professional&utm_medium=typeform&utm_content=typeform-embedded-poweredbytypeform&utm_term=EN" style="color: #999"
          target="_blank">Typeform</a> </div>
    </div>
  </body>

  </html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've implemented a Content Security Policy (CSP) that doesn't allow `unsafe-eval` in Javascript.  You have two choices:

1. Change your CSP to remove this restriction (though this creates security risks).
2. Don't use the typeform script.  Or contact typeform for a solution.  They should hopefully be able to provide a script that doesn't violate `unsafe-eval`.

Comment: Just reached out to typeform to see if there is some workaround to this issue. I am curious what the security risks are specifically. I have read how unwise it is to activate a python script from an html button, since it would be sending commands to your command line. But in this case, doesn't hosting on Google App Engine minimize this risk? As I'm assuming commands are run on the GAE server and not command line?

Comment: Also, do you mind commenting on where exactly I would change my CSP? I'm assuming the CSP line will look like ```"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"```